# Позиция NavigationView при возврате назад

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется одна ActivityMain и множество Fragment. Конкретно вопрос заденет 4 фрагмента - RuleListFragment, DirListFragment, TestFragment и SettingFragment (`extends PreferenceFragmentCompat`).
Навигация в приложении осуществляется с помощью Navigation Component, часть AndroidX.
В MainActivity определено - `appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder( R.id.ruleListFragment, R.id.dirListFragment, R.id.testFragment).setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout).build();`

При переходе между первыми тремя фрагментами через "гамбургер" проблем нет. При переходе к SettingFragment вместо "гамбургера" отображается стрелка назад (так и должно быть!). Если нажать назад, то происходит возврат к первому фрагменту независимо откуда был вызван SettingFragment. То есть если я вызвал фрагмент SettingFragment в то время когда я находился в DirListFragment, и после настройки нажал "назад", то возврат происходит к RuleListFragment.

Есть идея передать позицию, но не знаю как, или реализовать SettingFragment через DialogFragment.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    ...
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        ..>
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            ...>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                .../>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            ...
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        ...
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NavigationView"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_recycler.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    ... />
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
    ...>
    <SwitchPreference
        .../>
    <Preference
        .../>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavController navController;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.hostFragment);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.ruleListFragment, R.id.dirListFragment, R.id.testFragment)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

RuleListFragment.java

```
public class RuleListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RuleAdapter ruleAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        ...

        return view;
    }

    private class RuleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ...
    }

    private class RuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RuleHolder> {
       ...
    }
}
```

DirListFragment.java

```
ublic class DirListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
        ...
        return view;
    }
```

SettingFragment.java

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

menu_navigation.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group01" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/ruleListFragment" android:icon="@drawable/ic_book_black_24dp" android:title="RuleList"  />
        <item android:id="@+id/dirListFragment" android:icon="@drawable/ic_insert_chart_black_24dp" android:title="DirList" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group02" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/settingFragment" android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" android:title="Settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

navigation_graph.xml

```
<navigation
    ...
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/ruleListFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ruleListFragment"
        android:name="....Fragments.RuleListFragment"
        android:label="RuleListFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dirListFragment"
        android:name="....Fragments.DirListFragment"
        android:label="DirListFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="....Fragments.SettingFragment"
        android:label="Setting" />
</navigation>
```

Если переходить RuleListFragment -> SettingFragment, то возвращается к RuleListFragment.
Если переходить DirListFragment -> SettingFragment, то возвращается к RuleListFragment, а надо к DirListFragment.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень сложно понять что у вас происходит без кода. Приведите пожалуйста фрагменты кода, и добавьте конкретики

Comment: вы же используйте Navigation library, и у каждого фрагмента в графе нафигации имеется параметр, отвечающий за тот фрагмент, к которому возвращаться при клике назад. Откройте граф, выберите ваш фрагмент в Design и выберите соответствующий параметр

Comment: @danilshik Куда что добавить? Скрин вложил.

Comment: при добавлении action fragment у него есть параметр Pop to

Comment: @danilshik Возможно я некорректно объяснил. Кнопка назад работает, все хорошо. Проблема в том что при нажатии она всегда возвращает в стартовый фрагмент в не зависимости от того откуда был вызван.

Comment: @danilshik Смотри скрин который вложил, последний. Есть вот такое меню. В первых трех отображается "гамбургер", в последней (Settings) отображается стрелка назад. Теперь если я перейду по этому меню сперва в DirList, а потом в Settings, а потом нажму стрелку назад, то я попаду в RuleList, хотя ожидал что попаду в DirList. Аналогично с другими пунктами.

Comment: ну так он у вас является стартовым fragment, action между этими fragment нету, поэтому он и возвращается туда

Answer (score 0):

В файле меню нужно поставить `android:menuCategory="secondary"`